# Command fails running in Systemd timer script

Tags: find, cron, systemd, systemd-timer

I have backup script for Mysql that previously ran using CRON without issue. I migrated to using systemd timer. The script starts out deleting the previous weeks files before the copy, using this command;

```
find /home/NAS2/$SRVER/backups/$_DAY -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

What I get in messages log is this;

```
percona_backup: rm: cannot remove â€˜/home/NAS2/o71/backups/Monday/mysql/proc.ibdâ€™: No such file or directory
```

SELinux is set to enforced. I should mention, there are 3 servers running variation of the same script, only 2 are failing with this error. All comes down to this one command.

So, why would this work as CRON but fail with systemd timer?
Why would it work on 1, but same command fail on 2 other servers?

Comment: You may somehow be starting the same backup twice, simultaneously. Perhaps  the cron setup is still configured?

Comment: That was the first thing I thought of, and verified the cron job was not running.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the failure to remove files that have already been removed, then you can add the `--force` option to `rm`. From the `man rm` docs:

> ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt